# multiple call to startforeground?

Tags: android, service

i have created a service (EmailService) that sends email ... each time i need to send an email with my app, it starts the service and pass the id of the email via an intent...

i am using `startforeground(id_of_email, mynotifcation);` to prevent it from being killed and to show a notification to the user of the status of the email sending.

i need to allow the user to send multiple emails at the time, so when the user needs to send another email, it again calls `startservice` with a new intent(different id of email)...so it calls `startforeground(new_id_of_email, mynotifcation);` again.

the problem is that the new call to `startforeground` overwrites the previous notification... (so the user loses the previous notification and doesn't know what is going on with his previous email)

Comment: Won´t it be better to queue the tasks in database or something? that way, once the first is done, the service would update that to done or delete it and check for if there´s something else to do. Maybe a messagequeue to keep feeding the service with more tasks

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the `Service.startForeground()` source shows that multiple calls to startForeground will only replace the currently shown notification. In fact, the call to startForeground is identical to `stopForeground()`, only with `removeNotification` set always set to true.

If you wish for you service to display a notification for each email in progress, you will have to manage each notification individually from the service.

```
public final void startForeground(int id, Notification notification) {
    try {
        mActivityManager.setServiceForeground(
                new ComponentName(this, mClassName), mToken, id,
                notification, true);
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
    }
}

public final void stopForeground(boolean removeNotification) {
    try {
        mActivityManager.setServiceForeground(
                new ComponentName(this, mClassName), mToken, 0, 
                null, removeNotification);
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
    }
}
```

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/android/app/Service.java#Service.startForeground%28int%2Candroid.app.Notification%29

Answer (score 2):

One can also use `STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH` flag.

Quoting from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH) :

> STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH
>
> added in API level 24 int STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH Flag for
>   stopForeground(int): if set, the notification previously provided to
>   startForeground(int, Notification) will be detached from the service.
>   Only makes sense when STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE is not set -- in this
>   case, the notification will remain shown, but be completely detached
>   from the service and so no longer changed except through direct calls
>   to the notification manager.
>
> Constant Value: 2 (0x00000002)

So, before a repeated call to `startForeground()` you can call `stopForeground(STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH);`. This will detach the notification and repeated calls to `startForeground()` will not make modifications to it, **if** you use a different notification-id.

Further, the "detached" notification, now, does not represent the "ongoing service" and hence can be removed by user with a swipe.

**BONUS :**

For compatibility, one can use `ServiceCompat` class and its `static` method `ServiceCompat.stopForeground(MyService.this, STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH)` as is documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ServiceCompat.html).

Answer (score 0):

I created a utility class to manage foreground service notification(s) based on @zeekhuge's answer. You can find the snippet here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62604739/4522359