# Two or more Foreground Notification with Progress is replacing each other while updating its progress

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a service that will run a upload task in foreground then showing a progress in the notification. Since a user may upload multiple times with different id request then there will be two or more foreground service that will run. Everything works fine but what I want is to show all task's notification with progress with this code.

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID_DEFAULT)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_file_upload_white_24dp)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(caption)
            .setProgress(100, percentComplete, false)
            .setContentInfo(String.valueOf(percentComplete +"%"))
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setAutoCancel(false);

    NotificationManager manager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    manager.notify(code, builder.build());

    startForeground(code,builder.build());
```

But unfortunately the notification just get overwrites, but if I removed the startForeground() then everything works fine as it shows multiple progress notification according to how many task is ongoing but the system may kill the process if gets low memory that is why I wanted it to run in foreground. So how am I able to show a number of notification that is equal to the number of on going task in Foreground?

Comment: hi,  manager.notify(code, builder.build()); in that what is code ? That code should be unique. You are passing same code in both method. That is the issue.

Comment: Okay thanks I will try to generate unique ids but do I still need the notification manager here or the notification builder is enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I figure it out how to do it.
First I needed to run it inside a onCreate with a little delay.

```
 @Override
public void onCreate (){
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                startForeground(requestCode, getMyActivityNotification("",completedParts,totalSize));
        }
    },500);

}
```

Then create a notification provider method.

```
//Notification provider
private Notification getMyActivityNotification(String caption, long completedUnits, long totalUnits){

    int percentComplete = 0;
    if (totalUnits > 0) {
        percentComplete = (int) (100 * completedUnits / totalUnits);
    }

    //Return the latest progress of task
    return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID_DEFAULT)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_file_upload_white_24dp)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(caption)
            .setProgress(100, percentComplete, false)
            .setContentInfo(String.valueOf(percentComplete +"%"))
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .build();

}
```

Then updating notification progress should be separated from calling a foreground.

```
/**
 * Show notification with a progress bar.
 * Updating the progress happens here
 */
protected void showProgressNotification(String caption, long completedUnits, long totalUnits, int code) {

    createDefaultChannel();
    mCaption = caption;
    requestCode = code;
    completedParts = completedUnits;
    totalSize = totalUnits;

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (mNotificationManager != null) {
        //Update the notification bar progress
        mNotificationManager.notify(requestCode,  getMyActivityNotification(caption,completedUnits,totalUnits));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Before you call startForeground, you need to call `ServiceCompat.stopForeground(service, ServiceCompat.STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH)` to keep the old notification(s).

The following is a utility class that you can use in the foreground service to manage the notifications:

```
class ForegroundNotifications(
    private val context: Context,
    private val foregroundServiceHelper: ForegroundServiceHelper,
    private val notificationService: NotificationService
) {

    var activeNotificationId: Int? = null
        private set

    val notificationIds: Set<Int>
        get() = entries.keys

    val isEmpty: Boolean
        get() = entries.isEmpty()

    private val entries: LinkedHashMap<Int, Notification> = LinkedHashMap()

    fun notifyAndDetachPrevious(notificationId: Int, notification: Notification) {
        synchronized(this) {
            foregroundServiceHelper.startForegroundAndDetachPreviousNotification(
                notificationId,
                notification
            )

            entries[notificationId] = notification
            activeNotificationId = notificationId
        }
    }

    fun cancel(notificationId: Int) {
        synchronized(this) {
            if (notificationId == activeNotificationId) {
                val newActiveNotificationId = entries.keys.findLast { it != activeNotificationId }
                val notification = entries[newActiveNotificationId]

                if (newActiveNotificationId != null && notification != null) {
                    notifyAndDetachPrevious(newActiveNotificationId, notification)
                }
            }

            entries.remove(notificationId)

            if (isEmpty) {
                foregroundServiceHelper.stopForeground()
            } else {
                notificationService.cancel(context, id = notificationId)
            }
        }
    }

}

interface NotificationService {

    fun createDefaultChannel(context: Context)

    fun notify(context: Context, tag: String? = null, id: Int, notification: Notification)

    fun cancel(context: Context, tag: String? = null, id: Int)

}

interface ForegroundServiceHelper {

    fun startForegroundAndDetachPreviousNotification(
        notificationId: Int,
        notification: Notification
    )

    fun stopForeground()

}

class ForegroundServiceHelperImpl(
    private val service: Service
) : ForegroundServiceHelper {

    override fun startForegroundAndDetachPreviousNotification(
        notificationId: Int,
        notification: Notification
    ) {
        ServiceCompat.stopForeground(service, ServiceCompat.STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH)
        service.startForeground(notificationId, notification)
    }

    override fun stopForeground() {
        ServiceCompat.stopForeground(service, ServiceCompat.STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE)
    }

}
```

Comment: You didn't say how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Use different id for different notification. In this code, you are using same default id so new notification is replacing old one.

Comment: So it is possible to show multiple notification from different tasks under foreground?

Comment: yes it is, you just need to pass different id for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass different **Id** to get different notification.

In Your Code:

Use `getId()` method to get different Id for each notification:

```
private static final AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger(0);
 public static int getID() {
        return c.incrementAndGet();
    }

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID_DEFAULT)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_file_upload_white_24dp)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(caption)
            .setProgress(100, percentComplete, false)
            .setContentInfo(String.valueOf(percentComplete +"%"))
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setAutoCancel(false);

    NotificationManager manager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    manager.notify(getId(), builder.build());

    startForeground(getId(),builder.build()); // you need to pass different id here. Or i think this method is not there.
```

For android **O** you need notification channel:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications",                      NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            // Configure the notification channel.
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationChannel.setSound(notification, Notification.AUDIO_ATTRIBUTES_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSound(notification)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_visualogyx_notification)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message).setBigContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)))
                .setTicker("Hearty365")
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round));

        notificationManager.notify(getID(),notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Is that more appropriate than using this? int requestCode = ("Request upload" + System.currentTimeMillis()).hashCode();

Comment: Still not working the notification is simultaneously changing between two task.

Comment: Because you pass same Id in manger.notify() method and in startForeground() method.

Comment: Yes you need notification channel for android O . I will update my code.

Comment: So it supposed to be unique also in startForeground()?! Thanks guys

Comment: Yes. It should be unique. whenever you need Id. Please upvote my answer.

Comment: But now I am having a duplicate notification where in one of them is constantly pop up when the progress change.

Comment: i think  startForeground(getId(),builder.build());  this method is not required.

Comment: Yes as I have said everything works fine without it but unfortunately I do not want to kill the task when the system get low in memory that is why I need to put it to foreground.

Comment: have you passed different Id 's in both methods?

Comment: Yes I generate another unique id in startForeground() now in one task I am getting a two notification :<

Comment: means your problem is while app is in foreground notification is not coming?

Comment: No, your logic is working but not properly working. When uploading a single file it will run in foreground with notification progress. It suppose to be per task but now I am getting two notification in just one task. Now when uploading another file I am getting 3 notification

Comment: i think your method startForeground(getId(),builder.build()); shuold be in if else condition. First time will not be called. Then called.

Comment: hello, i think this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029431/how-to-correctly-handle-startforegrounds-two-notifications?rq=1 ans would be helpful