# Android foreground service multiple notifications for same service

Tags: android, android-notifications, foreground-service

I have a RecyclerView which has on each holder a start button to start a countdown timer, I start the countdown timer in a foreground service so that the user can leave the app or do whatever he wants and be aware of the timer, each time I start a timer the onStartCommand is called I know the service can run only in one instance and the problem is that the text on the notification is messed up and updates randomly all the launched countdowns! When I call the service I put an extra for each call to set different notification channel id but it's the same thing I get only one notification. I need a separate notification for each countdown timer so the user can see/control each one individually.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    timerServiceInstance = this;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //  startForeground(requestCode, getMyActivityNotification("",completedParts,totalSize));
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
        }
    }, 1);
}



@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    NOTIFICATION_ID = intent.getIntExtra("foreGroundID", 1);
    CHANNEL_ID = "channel_" + NOTIFICATION_ID;
    long millisInput = intent.getLongExtra("time", 0);

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.app_name);

        NotificationChannel mChannel =
                new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

        mChannel.setSound(null, null);
        mChannel.enableVibration(false);


        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }
    setTime(millisInput);
    startTimer();


    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}


private void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "Foreground Service Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        );
        serviceChannel.setSound(null, null);
        serviceChannel.enableVibration(false);
        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
    }
}

private void setTime(long milliseconds) {
    startTimeInMillis = milliseconds;
    resetTimer();
}

private void startTimer() {
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeLeftInMillis;
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
            updateCountDownText();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timerRunning = false;
            updateWatchInterface();
        }
    }.start();
    timerRunning = true;
    updateWatchInterface();
}

private void pauseTimer() {
    countDownTimer.cancel();
    timerRunning = false;
    Paper.book().write("timerTimeLeft", timeLeftInMillis);
    pauseResumeButtonText = "Resume";
    updateWatchInterface();
}

private void resetTimer() {
    timeLeftInMillis = startTimeInMillis;
    updateCountDownText();
    updateWatchInterface();
}

private void updateCountDownText() {
    int hours = (int) (timeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 3600;
    int minutes = (int) ((timeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 3600) / 60;
    int seconds = (int) (timeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;

    timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
            "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);

    // startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (mNotificationManager != null) {
        //Update the notification bar progress
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
    }
}

private void updateWatchInterface() {
    if (timerRunning) {
        pauseResumeButtonText = "Pause";
    } else {
        pauseResumeButtonText = "Resume";
        if (timeLeftInMillis == 0) {
            pauseResumeButtonText = "Done";
        }
        // startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (mNotificationManager != null) {
            //Update the notification bar progress
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
        }
    }
}

static public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getStringExtra("action");

        System.out.println("ACTION CLICKED IS " + action);
        switch (action) {
            case PAUSE_RESUME_TIMER:
                if (timerServiceInstance.timerRunning) {
                    timerServiceInstance.pauseTimer();
                } else {
                    long millisInput = Paper.book().read("timerTimeLeft");
                    timerServiceInstance.setTime(millisInput);
                    timerServiceInstance.startTimer();
                }
                break;
            case STOP_TIMER:
                Paper.book().write("timerTimeLeft", 0);
                timerServiceInstance.stopSelf();
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Try setting different notification Id

Comment: EDITED, I forget to mention that I am also using different notification IDs, but it's not working as well.

Comment: check this might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243494/two-or-more-foreground-notification-with-progress-is-replacing-each-other-while

Comment: Please write your source code. Meanwhile, I have posted an answer that you can use.

Comment: @ManoharReddy I managed to add the notification now but there is a new problem, it's like the timer is confused between which one to update!

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), xyz.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        String channelId = Constant.CHANNEL_NAME_ALL;
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(expandedTitle))
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        try{
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                        Constant.CHANNEL_DISTRICT_DATA,
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
            Random rand = new Random();
            notificationManager.notify(rand.nextInt(10000) /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The key here is using this code:

```
 Random rand = new Random();
            notificationManager.notify(rand.nextInt(10000) /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Sending notification using different ID result in the different notification and not same notification being updated.

[EDIT]

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    timerServiceInstance = this;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //  startForeground(requestCode, getMyActivityNotification("",completedParts,totalSize));
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
        }
    }, 1);
}



@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    NOTIFICATION_ID = intent.getIntExtra("foreGroundID", 1);
    CHANNEL_ID = "channel_" + NOTIFICATION_ID;
    long millisInput = intent.getLongExtra("time", 0);

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.app_name);

        NotificationChannel mChannel =
                new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

        mChannel.setSound(null, null);
        mChannel.enableVibration(false);


        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }
    setTime(millisInput);
    startTimer(NOTIFICATION_ID);


    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}


private void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "Foreground Service Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        );
        serviceChannel.setSound(null, null);
        serviceChannel.enableVibration(false);
        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
    }
}

private void setTime(long milliseconds) {
    startTimeInMillis = milliseconds;
    resetTimer();
}

private void startTimer(int N_ID) {
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeLeftInMillis;
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
            updateCountDownText(N_ID);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timerRunning = false;
            updateWatchInterface(N_ID);
        }
    }.start();
    timerRunning = true;
    updateWatchInterface(N_ID);
}

private void pauseTimer(int N_ID) {
    countDownTimer.cancel();
    timerRunning = false;
    Paper.book().write("timerTimeLeft", timeLeftInMillis);
    pauseResumeButtonText = "Resume";
    updateWatchInterface(N_ID);
}

private void resetTimer(int N_ID) {
    timeLeftInMillis = startTimeInMillis;
    updateCountDownText(N_ID);
    updateWatchInterface(N_ID);
}

private void updateCountDownText(int N_ID) {
    int hours = (int) (timeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 3600;
    int minutes = (int) ((timeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 3600) / 60;
    int seconds = (int) (timeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;

    timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
            "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);

    // startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (mNotificationManager != null) {
        //Update the notification bar progress
        mNotificationManager.notify(N_ID, getNotification());
    }
}

private void updateWatchInterface(int N_ID) {
    if (timerRunning) {
        pauseResumeButtonText = "Pause";
    } else {
        pauseResumeButtonText = "Resume";
        if (timeLeftInMillis == 0) {
            pauseResumeButtonText = "Done";
        }
        // startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (mNotificationManager != null) {
            //Update the notification bar progress
            mNotificationManager.notify(N_ID, getNotification());
        }
    }
}

static public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getStringExtra("action");

        System.out.println("ACTION CLICKED IS " + action);
        switch (action) {
            case PAUSE_RESUME_TIMER:
                if (timerServiceInstance.timerRunning) {
                    timerServiceInstance.pauseTimer();
                } else {
                    long millisInput = Paper.book().read("timerTimeLeft");
                    timerServiceInstance.setTime(millisInput);
                    timerServiceInstance.startTimer();
                }
                break;
            case STOP_TIMER:
                Paper.book().write("timerTimeLeft", 0);
                timerServiceInstance.stopSelf();
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I updated, check the code to understand, I managed to get the notification now, but the problem is how to control each one individually and organize each timer.

Comment: Use the notification ID to control the individual notification rand.nextInt(10000)

Comment: I don't need a random generator, I am already sending the ID with extra, the proper question is how to use the correct ID for each notification!

Comment: Are you sending a different ID for each notification? The best practice for using correct ID depends on you. You can use a timestamp dependency variable, long variable, or setup your logic based on the content you are sending.

Comment: Yes, I am sending fore each notification an ID, how can I control each notification separately.

Comment: Just to be there: you want to know the process of managing it or you want to know how to locate a particular notification. If 2nd one you want to know, then use individual ID. You can call NotificationManagerCompat.notify() to update the notification individually

Comment: I didn't really get what you meant, but I am pretty sure I am doing it wrong, the countdown timer isn't supposed to be made like that for multiple instances of timers, I still didn't get how to make it work properly!

Comment: I read the entire thread one more time. And I guess the problem is you cant update the text properly on each timer right?

Comment: Lemme know if I have identified it correctly. If that's the issue, you need to change the code a bit.

Comment: I am not really sure but I think I got it wrong, to make sure it's working I need to update each notification by its ID

Comment: I added a list and each time I add new notification ID I add it to the list now I am able to update each notification separately, and it's like I thought the I need to add a timer separately or something like that, it doesn't seem to work this way to implement multiple timers

Comment: I've posted an update. You definitely need to pass the individual ID for each update.

Comment: Please share your original code. Maybe in private. So that I can run it here and can fix it. I'm definitely sure that the problem lies within usage of NOTIFICATION ID because each time the timer wants to update the notification, it is using notification id which might before to previous notification or next notification in line.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I figured out the solution by creating a new timer class and add it into an array list now each notification is updating separately, but again I get a new problem when I click the pause button It pauses only the last add timer, for example I add 3 timer ID for each one is 1,2,3 when I want to pause 1 or 2 the only one that gets paused is 3, how can I know the ID of the clicked notification when it's clicked?

Comment: You can put a key in your PendingIntent. The key can be your notification ID too. Simply add it to your Intent and then PendingIntent. This way whatever action is executed after clicking, you can check there which notification is clicked using the Key.

Comment: Intent intentPauseResumeTimer = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);
            intentPauseResumeTimer.putExtra("action", PAUSE_RESUME_TIMER);
            intentPauseResumeTimer.putExtra("NOTIFICATION_ID",countDownId);
            PendingIntent pendingIntentPauseResumeTimer = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentPauseResumeTimer, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
I am putting the notification id same as countdown id, but it gets replaced by the last one.

Comment: Is the countDownId same as Notification ID? If that's the case, it should work. I will have to run the code at my end to check perfectly.

Comment: Yes countDownId is the same as Notification ID.

Answer (score -1):

To display multiple notifications you should use multiple notifications IDs.
not channel IDs.

i.e.
The one you define here:

```html
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
```

Comment: EDITED, I forget to mention that I am also using different notification IDs, but it's not working as well.